# MySQL 5.7 and Visual C++. Help to resolve linkage issue

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, linker

I installed MySQL 5.7. It works and I can connect it from Visual Studio Data Connection.

I want to access DB from my C++ code. I pass through this guide several times
[Building Connector/C++ Windows Applications with Microsoft Visual Studio](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html). And I still cannot link the simplest sample project.

I get linker errors like:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library SecondTry   D:\dev_projects\VCPP\SecondTry\SecondTry\LINK   1

or

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning LNK4049 locally defined symbol ??0exception@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z (public: __cdecl std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)) imported  SecondTry   D:\dev_projects\VCPP\SecondTry\SecondTry\mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset_metadata.obj)  1

I tried different types of Runtime Library (MD/MDd etc). I still cannot link the project.

Please, advise me, how overcome this problem.

Comment: The first issue is a _warning_ and shouldn't prevent you from linking. The second issue looks like something you would get by using `/NODEFAULTLIB` which isn't the solution here. Chances are one of the third party libraries you are linking against was built against an older or different version of MSVCRT. You'll need to identify which library is causing the conflict and update to the latest most correct version for your tool chain.

Comment: This error happens in a new project MFC dialog based project. Nothing else except MFC and Connector/C. How can I check what lib cause this error?